# Access google big query data from external source. Keep getting 403 error

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, authorization, http-status-code-403

I am trying to connect BigQuery to Jetadmin, a no-code data display site. I have tried multiple ways to give access but I cannot figure it out and google documentation seems very confusing (i'm not a great coder).  I have created a service account in IAM and given the following roles: BigQuery Data Editor, BigQuery Data Owner, BigQuery Data Viewer, BigQuery Job User, Storage Object Viewer.  To connect to Jetadmin I provide the JSON key, I have tried a variety of IAM roles in the relevant project in BigQuery.  Whenever I run a basic SQL request on jetadmin I get:

```
(google.cloud.bigquery.dbapi.exceptions.DatabaseError) 403 Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials.

"Location: US
Job ID: 2c896046-85d0-4b3b-bf35-ea5a772d2e39

`[SQL: SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM `pricing-data-377922.Test1.Bigin`) AS `__jet_q2`
 LIMIT %(param_1:INT64)s]
[parameters: {'param_1': 100}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/4xp6)"`
```

Does anyone know how I can provide access through BigQuery? This is a solo project and I have full control over permissions and things of that nature.  Can anyone help with this?

I tried to access BigQuery through a nocode site called Jetadmin.  No matter what auths I gave to the service account I got a 403 access denied from BigQuery.

I tried to connect through JSON key.

Comment: 403 is a http(s) error, maybe you are looking for something different like RESRT aPi

Comment: It is a REST API that is connecting with BigQuery. Are you familiar with BigQuery? And if so do you know the authentications I need to give the service account?

Comment: *Permission denied while getting `Drive` credentials.* --> Are you using *Google Drive* somewhere in Jetadmin ?

Comment: @Jaytiger Yes I have google sheets connected to JetAdmin. I will try to disconnect it and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting BQ to read data from GDrive probably you have to share the source file (Sheet?) with the service account (share by email address of the service account).

Comment: I have google sheets connected but am not using it to connect to JetAdmin.  I am trying to directly connect to BigQuery with the JSON key but I keep getting 403 errors (Unauthorized) despite granting all the necessary user roles to the service account.  Do you have any ideas as to why I still can't get access?

Comment: Difficult to help without specific details about configurations, accounts etc

Comment: My service account "test2pleasework" has the following roles: BigQuery Admin, BigQuery Data Viewer, BigQuery Job User, Owner, Storage Admin.  The project it has access to has one dataset and one table within the dataset.  I connect to BigQuery through the JetAdmin API (on the JetAdmin application) and enter the JSON key (when I test connection with the button it works). Then I try to run the SQL command: SELECT * FROM 'dataset' in JetAdmin and I get the 403 Error message saying that I do not have access to the dataset despite putting my JSON key in. Thank you for helping Fabio B.!

Comment: You have to include the table name in the query, not only the dataset. To perform reading, viewer roles normally are enough, storage admin is to much... Just share the sheet file with the email of the service account. Test your query on the BQ user interface.

Comment: Ok I will redo the user permissions.  I have been using the table I want to reference in the SQL query.  When I use it in the BQ user interface it works. but I get 403 Authorization Denied when I try to query in JetAdmin.  What do you mean by "share the sheet file with the email of the service account"

Comment: When you use BG UI it works because your are project owner or editor, and you have access to the Sheet file on GDrive right? Now, the service authenticates using the service account, so also that account needs access to the Sheet file. To provide the access, you have to go to the GDrive, select the Sheet file and do Share with ... email of the service account. In such way the service account can access the Sheet